# Laravel Auth Session Missing After Redirect(with web middleware)

Tags: php, laravel

im using laravel 7.14
I'm using laravel's Auth to do a login process and keep my application authenticated using username and password in my database. Here is my route:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'web'], function () {
    Route::post('/user/login', 'UserController@loginUser');
});
```

and my login function

```
public function loginUser(Request $request)
{
    $field = 'email';
    if (is_numeric(Request()->username)) {
        $field = 'mobile';
    } elseif (filter_var(Request()->username, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        $field = 'email';
    }

    if ($field == "mobile") {
        $user = User::where("mobile",'=',Request()->username)->first();
    }
    else{
        $user = User::where("email",'=',Request()->username)->first();
    }
    if($user){
        Auth::login($user, Request()->filled('remember'));
        $data = ["status" => true,"mobile_verified" => Auth::user()->mobile_verified];
        return response($data)
            ->header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", config('cors.allowed_origins'))
            ->header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", config('cors.allowed_methods'));
    }
    else
    {
        $data = ["status" => false];
        return response($data)
            ->header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", config('cors.allowed_origins'))
            ->header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", config('cors.allowed_methods'));

    }
}
```

but after redirect i check Auth::guest() and it is true.
i searched a lot and solutions is use of web middleware but its not work for me

UPDATE:
My User Model Is:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name','family', 'email','mobile','tel','state','city','verification_code','district','address','role', 'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];
}
```

Comment: Hi,can you share your User model code ?

Comment: yes. i updated.